# Ruby: How do determine the value of the high order bit of an integer?

Tags: ruby, binary, bit-shift

I have an integer `common_bits` and am trying to determine the value of the high order (leftmost) bit. If the bit is a `1` I want to shift left by 1 bit (`common_bits = common_bits << 1`) and increment a counter `bitlength`.

I have tried to `AND` a mask with `common_bits` within a `while` statement such that if the high order bit is a `1 common_bits` will be shifted left. It doesn't work, however, and I end up with a high order 1 bit in `common_bits` after the `while` terminates.

```
CHECK_MASK = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000

bitlength = 0
p "Starting common_bits is #{common_bits.to_s(2)}"

while ((common_bits & CHECK_MASK) == CHECK_MASK)
  common_bits = (common_bits << 1) & 0xffffffff 
  bitlength = bitlength + 1
  p "bitlength is #{bitlength}. common_bits is #{common_bits.to_s(2)}"
end

p "Final common_bits is #{common_bits.to_s(2)}"
p "Final bitlength is #{bitlength}"
```

I've considered converting the integer to a binary string (`common_bits.to_s(2)`) and traversing the string, but I feel like there has to be a much cleaner and more direct way.

Comment: Your code works for me. How are you confirming that the bit is set afterwards? I assume you are aware that there is no real "top bit" in Ruby numbers, it can happily work with huge Integers e.g. `2**500000 -1` . . . so is your problem just that you expect it to truncate at 32 (or 64) bits?

Comment: Have a look at [this question and the checkmarked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445760/bit-shifting-in-ruby).

Comment: @NeilSlater I convert the integer to a binary string and the output is a string 32-characters long with the leftmost bit set to 1. The integers I'm dealing with here are IPv4 addresses so they should never exceed 32-bits in length.

Comment: Sometimes it's a lot easier to work with strings than binary. All's fair when it comes to looking at values and whether there's a bit set or not. I used strings when checking IP masks for zero-bits, which made it a very straightforward test.

Comment: @Ben show your conversion and test code. I think you are assuming 32-bits somewhere incorrectly. The string is likely 33 or more characters long if the high bits have been shifted out, or may even be shorter and you are just seeing the highest set bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby will not truncate integers to 32 bits for you, or to any specific bit length. It will instead "upgrade" internal representations to `Bignum` class if necessary and keep going. 32 bits is not a limit, neither is 64, neither is 1024 . . .

So if you need an Integer kept in bounds to e.g. 32 bits unsigned, you have to do it yourself, after any operation where it could overflow:

```
CHECK_MASK = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000

while ((common_bits & CHECK_MASK) == CHECK_MASK)
      common_bits = (common_bits << 1) & 0xffffffff
end
```

Comment: This was exactly what was missing. I've updated the original question to reflect the now-working code. Thanks!